# Configure an EFI boot menu for multiple Linux distros on an external SSD? (MacBook Pro)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, osx, kali-linux, refind

I’m recently new to Linux but coming from a macOS background, I like the look and feel of Linux and it’s very powerful.

I bought an external SSD and installed Kali for a career in pentesting (via Live USB), but I’m interested in installing Mint along side it (and maybe Ubuntu and Debian). I’d like to configure a boot loader which lets me select the distro when the SSD is plugged in. Currently with just Kali installed on the SSD, it just boots straight to Kali - I don't need to hold the macOS option key to choose EFI boot menu.

I've tried partitioning the SSD using macOS Disk Utility, and hoped to install Kali on one of the partitions but it didn't let me pick a partition during the Kali install, it just erased the disk and installed onto the whole disk.

I'd like to be able to see a similar boot menu to macOS EFI when I plug in the SSD, and be able to choose which distro of Linux to boot. All I can find is [rEFInd Boot Manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and it seems a bit complex to setup - [here's a guide I found for rEFInd to boot 5 different Linux distros.](https://medium.com/@manujarvinen/setting-up-a-multi-boot-of-5-linux-distributions-ca1fcf8d502)

If I use follow the above guide and use rEFInd, will it definitely install it on the external SSD? I've read a bit and I'm not sure if it installs rEFInd on macOS itself - I definitely don't want to overwrite my internal SSD somehow! If rEFInd installs to macOS but keeps my data, I'm ok with that if there are no repercussions.

I've searched this question on various Stack Exchange sites, and some are very technical. If this is the case, then I probably won't risk it in case I erase my internal SSD lol.

Thanks in advance!